# Why are parameters promoted when it comes to a variadic function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Why are parameters promoted when it comes to a variadic function,for instance floats are promoted to double ext and in which order are they promoted?

[Variadic arguments - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)

> #### Default conversions
>
> When a variadic function is called, after lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer [conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Value_transformations), each argument that is a part of the variable argument list undergoes additional conversions known as *default argument promotions*:
>
> - [std::nullptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) is converted to void*
> - float arguments are converted to double as in [floating-point promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Floating-point_promotion)
> - bool, char, short, and unscoped enumerations are converted to int or wider integer types as in [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion)

Comment: Most answer for *"why"* is *"because standard says so"*...

Comment: @Jarod42 disagree. Standard was not given to us as divine revelation, but instead created as a collaboration of engineers, and majority of decisions made there can be explained.

Comment: I think question is: what is rationale that standard has such requirement. Most probably performance and memory alignment, but this require more precise explanation or at least link to paper which explains that.

Comment: @SergeyA: There are possible rationale and trade-of made to explain why standard is like that. Other decision might have been chosen. A "generic" "why" question might be rewritten IMO like Marek R did for example.

Comment: I tried screening through http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf and https://jslint.com/chistory.html . The only worth mention is `For compatibility with past practice, all argument promotions occur as described in K&R in the absence of a prototype declaration`. Why the "past practices" promoted arguments, someone better in history will have to dig.

Comment: I wonder if `C` tag isn't better for this one, after all this is `C` feature which `C++` simply inherited.

Comment: @KamilCuk the context of the quoted text is calling a function with undeclared (i.e. empty) parameter list; not calling a function declared with a variable parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

Promotion of arguments for variadic functions make it way more easier to deal with them. Since the function code doesn't know the actual type of arguments from the function signature, calling has to communicate the type through some other means, and promotion reduces the number of options without sacrificing the flexibility.

For example, consider classical example of variadic function - `printf`. When you give it `%f` argument, it already knows that the argument is double precision, since it would be promoted. Absence promotion, two different modifiers would have to exist, one for single precision and another one for double precision.

Another example would be integral promotions. Currently any type would work with `%d` modifier, and while modifiers for short versions do exist, one is not required to use them, and can simplify their code.

In addition, it provides for fewer surprises when using some other variadic functions. For example, Posix `open` function is shown as if it would be an overloaded function with either 2 or 3 arguments, last argument being specified in the [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) as `mode_t` type. In fact, there are no overloads in C, so there are no two versions of `open` - there is only one, which is a variadic one.

Absent of promotions, one would have to make sure that when 3-argument version is used, the last argument is exactly `mode_t` type, which would be quite inconvenient, counterintuitive and failure to do so would likely lead to quite unexpected behavior. Automatic promotions save us from this.

Comment: But there *are* format specifiers for narrow types like `%hu` for `unsigned short` and `hhi` for `signed char`.

Comment: @eerorika I do not think they are mandatory to implement.

Comment: I couldn't find it mentioned in the standard that their implementation wouldn't be mandatory.

Comment: @eerorika perhaps, but what's more important, they are not mandatory to use :) One can use %d and give it a short argument, it would "just work". Yet I will edit the answer to better reflect on this.

Comment: How about using %u with unsigned short, and thereby accidentally end up printing a signed int with %u?

Comment: Eh, I don't think it's about the function having to worry about those types. Rather it's the  `va_arg` macro. I never implemented it, but I would imagine it's much less a PITA when most small types are promoted on the caller side.

Comment: @eerorika `hh` is just newly added since C99

Answer (score 1):

> Why are parameters promoted

*Because that is how the language has been specified.*

You may be thinking, why has the language been specified that way. I don't know if there is published rationale for this choice, but I suspect that the answer is as simple as: *Because that is how the C language had been specified*

You may be thinking, why was the C language specified that way. There is a standard document N1256 discussing design rationale of some choices for the C99 standard. It seems to not cover this choice. Besides, C language existed long before its standardisation and C99 wasn't even the first standard version. This behaviour may have existed before the involvement of the committee.

For what it's worth, same promotion rules apply also to calling functions that haven't been declared (until C99) or calling a fixed argument function through a prototype which doesn't declare the parameters:

```
// this is C lanugage
void fun();

int main(int, char [][]) {
    float f = 42;
    fun(f); // argument promotes to double

    undeclared(f); // ill-formed since C99
                   // argument promotes to double prior to C99
```

The reasons for this may be similar to the reasons for promotion in case of variable parameter lists.